# Solving linear programming without solving linear programming

Tags: linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, linear-programming, semidefinite-programming

Let $v_1, \cdots, v_n$ be vectors in $\mathbb R^k$, and let $M$ be the Gram matrix of them.

It's possible to determine from $M$ and $k$ whether the only vector that has nonnegative inner product with every $v_m$ is the zero vector. This is because $M$ determines $v_1, \cdots, v_n$ up to orthogonal transformations.

Nevertheless, the process of determining is as hard as linear programming. With this in mind, my question is:

**Question:** Are there sufficient conditions on $M$ and $k$ to ensure that the zero vector is the only vector that has nonnegative inner product with every $v_m$, without using linear programming?

What I would expect as answers are analytic conditions on the matrix $M$ and $k$ **without quantifiers** for any fixed $n$ and $k$.

**Example:** Assume $n=k+1$, and $X$ is the $n$-dimensional matrix with positive elements on the diagonal and negative elements elsewhere. Then $X$ as a Gram matrix satisfies the property.

Comment: Have you tried using quantifier elimination? Say, in Mathematica?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Suppose that $\det M_{J,J}\ne0$ for some set $J\subseteq[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$ of cardinality $|J|=k$, where $M_{J,J}:=(v_i\cdot v_j\colon (i,j)\in J\times J)$, the $(J\times J)$-submatrix of the Gram matrix $M$. Suppose also that $Mc=0$ for some $c=[c_1,\dots,c_n]^\top\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $c_j\ge0$ for all $j\in[n]$ and $c_j>0$ for all $j\in J$.

Then the zero vector is the only vector that has nonnegative inner product with every $v_i$.

---

Indeed, let $v:=\sum_{j\in[n]}c_j v_j\in\R^k$. Then
$$v_i\cdot v=\sum_{j\in[n]}c_j v_i\cdot v_j=(Mc)_i=0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
for all $i\in[n]$. Since $\det M_{J,J}\ne0$ and $|J|=k$, the rank of the Gram matrix $M$ is $\ge k$. That is, the rank of the system $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ of vectors is $\ge k$ (so, in fact, $=k$). So, by \eqref{1},
$$0=v=\sum_{j\in[n]}c_j v_j\in\R^k.\tag{2}\label{2}$$

Take now any $w\in\R^k$ such that $w\cdot v_j\ge0$ for all $j\in[n]$. By \eqref{2},
$$0=\sum_{j\in[n]}c_j w\cdot v_j.\tag{3}\label{3}$$
Since $c_j\ge0$ for all $j\in[n]$, all the summands in the sum in \eqref{3} are $\ge0$ and therefore $=0$. Since $c_j>0$ for all $j\in J$, it follows that $w\cdot v_j=0$ for all $j\in J$. But the rank of the system $(v_j\colon j\in J)$ of vectors is the same as the rank of $M_{J,J}$, which latter is $k$. We conclude that $w=0$, as claimed.

---

Letting $c_j=1$ for all $j\in[n]$ and taking any subset $J$ of $[n]$ of cardinality $k$, we see that the sufficient conditions given in beginning of this answer generalize the conditions in your Example.

I think it should be not hard to show that these sufficient conditions are also necessary. However, since you asked only for sufficient conditions, this addition should be the subject of another question, perhaps posted elsewhere.

Comment: This is the duality formulation of linear programming. Finding $c$ is the hard problem to avoid, and this is precisely why there is such a question. What I expect is an answer that eliminates the quantifier "for some $c$".

Comment: @LeechLattice : I did not mean solving the equation $Mc=0$ for $c$. I meant generalizing your example by acting apparently similarly to how you were acting when constructing your example. Namely, start with any linearly independent vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k$ in $\mathbb R^k$. Let $v_{k+1}:=-c_1v_2-\cdots-c_kv_k$ for some $c_1,\dots,c_k>0$. For any $n>k$, take any vectors $v_{k+2},\dots,v_n$ in $\mathbb R^k$. Let $M$ be the Gram matrix of $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ and let $c:=(c_1,\dots,c_k,1,0,\dots,0)\in\mathbb R^n$. Then $Mc=0$. This way, one can generate any number of examples similar to yours.

Comment: @LeechLattice : Your question requesting "a generalization of the example but without depending too much on a specific matrix (in the example, the matrix $X$) and the precise relationship between $n$ and $k$" is unclear. In particular, it is unclear what you mean by "generalization" and by "specific". It is also unclear how broad you want the sufficient condition to be. If you want it to be close to necessary, then it should be clear that you cannot avoid something close to linear programming.

Comment: The question is edited. There is no need to be close to necessary, because that inevitably leads to linear programming. The point is to find different kinds of sufficient conditions that may have applications in different circumstances.

Comment: @LeechLattice : After this edit, it is unclear what what you mean by "analytic". Say, is the condition that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ analytic? Is the condition that $M$ belong to a given finite set of matrices analytic? Also, is the latter condition broad enough? I guess not, but what condition would be broad enough? Also, it is unclear what you mean by "without quantifiers". If you go all the way back to the set of all real numbers, I think you cannot do without quantifiers.

Comment: In my first comment here, there was a typo: of course, there should be $v_1$ there in place of $v_2$.